# CSV to python list of dicts?

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I looked through the questions already posted and my problems isn't quite solved.  I think this should be fairly straight forward but I am getting tripped up with the variations. Hoping that after getting walked through this one file, then I can upload and parse the rest.

What I am trying to do:

- File is open states data (and other files in [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sm/create/data_science%202014)): ca_bills.csv
- Convert .csv to python: I think it should be converted to a python list of dicts
- Use the headers in the file as keys within dicts

I tried this but it didn't do what I wanted + I wonder if there is way to pull the fieldname from the headers of each file

```
    def csv_dict_writer(fp, fieldnames, data):
        with open(fp, "wb") as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, deliminter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I also did this but this only prints and doesn't write to a file:

```
    with open('ca_bills.csv') as output_file:
        reader = csv.reader(output_file)
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

Thanks so much! This may be similar to other question but really couldn't extract what I needed. Appreciate your insights.

Comment: You want to use a `DictReader`, not a `DictWriter`. Readers turn CSV files into Python data structures, writers do the opposite.

Answer (score 3):

```
result=list(csv.DictReader(fp))
```